# Python strings and substrings

Tags: python, string, function, arguments, substring

I have to write a Python function that takes a list of strings as its argument. The function should then print those strings in the list that contain as substrings either "cat" or "dog".

This is the code I have but nothing comes up when I run the code in Python:

```
def check_string(string_list):
    for word in string_list:
       if "cat" in word or "dog" in word:
    print(word)
```

Comment: Where (and with what) do you *call* that function?

Comment: Seems print is misplaced. It should be part of If statement.Please rectify and also try to post questions with appropriate examples.

Answer (score 1):

You just have some **indentation** issues.

```py
def check_string(string_list):
    for word in string_list:
       if "cat" in word or "dog" in word:
            print(word)
```